# How do I change the output of Angular ng-src from the 'src' attribute to 'data-src'?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, owl-carousel

I'm using the jquery plugin, OwlCarousel, with an ng-repeat scenario in one of my views like so:

```
<div owl-carousel-item="" ng-repeat="item in items" class="item">
        <img id="image{{ $index }}" data-ng-src="http://uploads.mysite.com/{{ article.photoURL }}" class="lazyOwl" />
</div>
```

It works well and outputs the following markup for each item in the carousel:

```
<img id="image0" data-ng-src="http://uploads.mysite.co/rs/e1f7daf77d42537212d31d8dbd113ec8.jpg" class="lazyOwl" src="http://uploads.mysite.co/rs/e1f7daf77d42537212d31d8dbd113ec8.jpg">
```

Is there a way to make the output render '`data-src=...`' instead of just '`src=...`'?

Comment: did you just delete the previous question you had asked with essentially the same body that already had comments and suggestions, only to ask the exact same question again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ng-attr` instead. `ng-src` is just a special case.

Comment: as in `'ng-attr-data-src=...'`  ?

Comment: Now I just need to work on the firing order and I'll be all set! :) Thanks for the guidance!

Comment: @DanielA.White I had a different problem that on first time the image is not loading. can you please check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33233657/owlcarousel-angular-js-image-src-tag-not-updating-the-value