# OwlCarousel Angular js image src tag not updating the value.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, carousel, owl-carousel

Have a slide build on owl carousel. Have tried to add feature lazy load to the image.

Below is my image tag written in html and its not showing the first image in the slide.

```
   <img class="multilink-image owl-lazy"
     data-src="{{ ::mycontroller.src }}">
```

In my browser it seams the above tag becomes as.

```
<img class="multilink-image owl-lazy" 
  data-src="//www.sampel.com/media/test.jpg" 
  src="{{ ::mycontroller.src }}">
```

The src tag is not updating the value. But on sliding the second image onwards its working fine. But still the first image fails to load.

Any help please

Comment: try using `ng-src` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

Comment: @ste2425 src tag is added by the carousel plugin.